# Set headers based on condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working on a react application, where i am checking for the availability of token in local storage, based on the token existence i need to set the headers.

I have tried by initially initializing the JavaScript object outside the loop and then set the headers in the if else condition.

```
getAllTopics() {
       const token = localStorage.getItem('authKey');
       var config = {};

       if(token){
         const URL = API_URL + `api/get-home-ideas-auth`;
          var config = {
           'Accept' : 'application/json',
           'Authorization' : `Bearer ` + token
       }

       } else {
         const URL = API_URL + `api/get-home-ideas`;
            var config = {
           'Accept' : 'application/json'
       }

       }
         axios.get(URL, {headers : config})
           .then(res => {
             if (res.data && res.data.status === 1) {
               const topics = res.data.data;
               console.log(topics);
               this.setState({ topics: topics, showloader:false});
             } 

           })
           .catch(e => {console.error(e); throw e;});
       }
```

I am getting error `Cannot GET /function URL()[nativecode]`

Comment: You should set the first config and then set it directly inside the condition.
Basically you created 3 different config variables at different scopes and the one that is used it the first one.

Comment: You don't have to concatenate using `+` if you're using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)` 'Authorization' : \`Bearer  ${token}\``

Comment: @techguru, see my solution below and let me know if that helps you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scoping issue, the problem is you initialize a new `config` variable inside the **if-else blocks** instead of referencing the one already defined outside of the scope. The new `config` variable is not accessible outside the private **if-else** scope. The outer `config` is never actually updated.

Just refer to the original `config` like so:

```
getAllTopics() {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('authKey');
   var config = {};
   var URL = '';
   if(token){
     URL = API_URL + "api/get-home-ideas-auth";
      config = {
         'Accept' : 'application/json',
         'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`
      }

   } else {
     URL = API_URL + "api/get-home-ideas";
        config = {
          'Accept' : 'application/json'
        }
   }

     axios.get(URL, {headers : config})
       .then(res => {
         if (res.data && res.data.status === 1) {
           const topics = res.data.data;
           console.log(topics);
           this.setState({ topics: topics, showloader:false});
         } 

       })
       .catch(e => {console.error(e); throw e;});
   }
```

Comment: Hi  @Christopher Ngo thanks for the help, there was a scoping issue with `URL` variable also, i updated your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
getAllTopics() {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('authKey');
   const URL = API_URL + `api/get-home-ideas-auth`;
   var config = {
   'Accept' : 'application/json',
   ...(token && {'Authorization' : `Bearer ` + token})
  }

     axios.get(URL, {headers : config})
       .then(res => {
         if (res.data && res.data.status === 1) {
           const topics = res.data.data;
           console.log(topics);
           this.setState({ topics: topics, showloader:false});
         } 

       })
       .catch(e => {console.error(e); throw e;});
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although already answered, the most clean way to do this is through *interceptors*:

```
/**
 * Create an Axios Client with defaults
 */
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: API.BASE_URL,
});

/*
* Request interceptor
* Useful for refreshing token before to make a new request and get 401 responses
*/
client.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const originalRequest = _.cloneDeep(config);
    // Using lodash _.set() we avoid undefined keys in path
    _.set(originalRequest, 'headers.Authorization', getAuth());
    return originalRequest;
  },
  err => Promise.reject(err),
);
```